# Python - Pandas, Rolling Mean, and difficult Groupby common ID with a few select parameters

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am having trouble creating the desired output from a rolling mean and groupby function in python.  Below is a snapshot of my dataframe....

```
    var_x = range(0, 12)
    var_y = range(20, 44, 2)
    var_z = range(0, 60, 5) 
    ID = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
    df = DataFrame(zip(ID, var_x, var_y, var_z), columns = ['id', 'var_x', 'var_y', 'var_z'])

    df
    id   var_x   var_y   var_z
    a   0  20   0
    a   1  22   5
    a   2  24  10
    a   3  26  15
    b   4  28  20
    b   5  30  25
    b   6  32  30
    b   7  34  35
    b   8  36  40
    c   9  38  45
    c  10  40  50
    c  11  42  55
```

With this data I am trying to accomplish 3 things:
- First I want to calculate the rolling mean using groupby for the 'id' field.  I am able to do this for an individual column but not for, lets say every numerical field (var_y, var_z), using the following code.

```
    df.groupby('id')['var_x'].apply(pd.rolling_mean, 3)
```

- Second,  I would like the average of the previous 3 IDs to populate the current ID, without the values of the current ID included in the current rolling mean iteration (maybe with shift?).  For example, an output that looks like this...

  ```
  0    NaN    NaN    NaN
  1    NaN    NaN    NaN
  2    NaN    NaN    NaN
  3      1    22     5
  4    NaN    NaN    NaN
  5    NaN    NaN    NaN
  6    NaN    NaN    NaN 
  7      5    30     25
  8      6    32     30
  9     NaN   NaN    NaN
  10    NaN   NaN    NaN
  11    NaN   NaN    NaN
  ```

Notice how the 4th 'a', is the average of the first 3 a's.  The same goes for the 4th and 5th b (taking on the values of the previous 3 averages while excluding its own values).

- Third, for the IDs that end up with 'NaN' (the first three for every new ID) I would like to iteratively reduce the window from 3 down to 1 (if possible) so that the only values with NaN will be the first instance for each ID.  Output desired will be...

  ```
  0    NaN    NaN    NaN
  1      0    20     0
  2    0.5    21     2.5
  3      1    22     5
  4    NaN    NaN    NaN
  5      4    28     20
  6    4.5    29     22.5 
  7      5    30     25
  8      6    32     30
  9     NaN   NaN    NaN
  10    9     38     45
  11    9.5   39     47.5
  ```

Notice how the 3rd a is the average of the first 2 a's.  the second a is the values from the first etc...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest for you to split your questions in separate posts.

Comment: That is a fair point, but I think it's probably OK in this case to do as 3, only the third one takes much effort.

Comment: Thanks,  ya the third part to the problem is a mind bender for me personally...  but any help on the first to is still greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with a slight change to the sample data by making 'id' the index.  This is mainly to simplify the data by saving a column, but also has the side effect of solving problem 1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var_x':range(12), 'var_y':range(20,44,2), 'var_z':range(0,60,5)}, 
                   index=list('aaaabbbbbccc'))

   var_x  var_y  var_z
a      0     20      0
a      1     22      5
a      2     24     10
a      3     26     15
b      4     28     20
b      5     30     25
b      6     32     30
b      7     34     35
b      8     36     40
c      9     38     45
c     10     40     50
c     11     42     55
```

Because of the data change, you also change the groupby syntax to `level=0`.  To be honest, I'm not quite sure why this solves your first problem, but I'm sure there's a way to do it without setting the index to the 'id' variable.  Anyway...

```
df2 = df.groupby(level=0).apply(pd.rolling_mean, 3)

   var_x  var_y  var_z
a    NaN    NaN    NaN
a    NaN    NaN    NaN
a      1     22      5
a      2     24     10
b    NaN    NaN    NaN
b    NaN    NaN    NaN
b      5     30     25
b      6     32     30
b      7     34     35
c    NaN    NaN    NaN
c    NaN    NaN    NaN
c     10     40     50
```

Second part is easy, just another groupby, but this time with shift.

```
df_win3 = df2.groupby(level=0).shift()

   var_x  var_y  var_z
a    NaN    NaN    NaN
a    NaN    NaN    NaN
a    NaN    NaN    NaN
a      1     22      5
b    NaN    NaN    NaN
b    NaN    NaN    NaN
b    NaN    NaN    NaN
b      5     30     25
b      6     32     30
c    NaN    NaN    NaN
c    NaN    NaN    NaN
c    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

The third part is just to repeat the first 2 steps with different windows.

```
df_win2 = df.groupby(level=0).apply(pd.rolling_mean, 2).groupby(level=0).shift()
df_win1 = df.groupby(level=0).apply(pd.rolling_mean, 1).groupby(level=0).shift()
```

Then use `combine_first` to merge where values are kept from the left-most dataframe if available.

```
df_win3.combine_first(df_win2).combine_first(df_win1)

   var_x  var_y  var_z
a    NaN    NaN    NaN
a    0.0     20    0.0
a    0.5     21    2.5
a    1.0     22    5.0
b    NaN    NaN    NaN
b    4.0     28   20.0
b    4.5     29   22.5
b    5.0     30   25.0
b    6.0     32   30.0
c    NaN    NaN    NaN
c    9.0     38   45.0
c    9.5     39   47.5
```

Comment: Thanks John, that is what I am looking for in my output and I was able to make it work with the original data set with grouping by the id, and passing a list of vectors to do the rolling_mean on....   All = ['var_x', 'var_y', 'var_z']                                                                                                       then...        df.groupby(df['id'])[All].apply(pd.rolling_mean, 3).groupby(df['id']).shift()